# How do I close the source of an AppleScript application?

Tags: applescript

When saving an AppleScript as an application, you can view the source by looking in the package contents. Recently, [ruddfawcett](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/21634/ruddfawcett) posted [his AD search application](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4401198#4401198) he made with AppleScript and the source was closed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the **Save As** dialog, there's a box that says "Run only". Check that when you save.

[image]

Comment: Be sure to save a copy of your source code when making a Run Only App. It's annoying to have to write a new script from scratch just because you want to make a tiny change to something that only exists as run only. The process *is* one way.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Now that you posted that, I remember doing it before :-) Thanks so much!